# Webstorm git-svn integration

Tags: git, svn, intellij-idea, webstorm, git-svn

We do not run a git remote repository. We only use git as a local vcs and push our code to a remote subversion repository via git-svn.

For now I am using the terminal for all my `git` and `git svn` actions. I'd like to use the gui for this in the future.

Is there a possibility to push local changes made in the git clone to a subversion remote via `git svn dcommit` directly from the webstorm interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately WebStorm don't have this feature yet.

Request for that was [created](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-26427) JetBrains.